# Подходит ли Go для написания Web-приложений?

Tags: golang, web-apps

Подходит ли Go для написания Web-приложений?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вполне. На сайте http://golang.org есть пример вики-приложения.

Ниже пример простейшей записной книжки наподобие гостевой на Go.

Файл гостевая.go.

```
package main

import (
    "http"
    "template"
)

const всего = 16
var последняя = 0

type записи struct {
    сообщение [всего]string
}
var гостевая записи

var шаблон *template.Template = template.MustParseFile("шаблон.html", nil)

func увидеть(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ошибка := шаблон.Execute(&гостевая, w)
    if ошибка != nil {
        http.Error(w, ошибка.String(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

func добавить(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if последняя < всего {
        гостевая.сообщение[последняя] = r.FormValue("body")
        последняя++
    }
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/увидеть/", http.StatusFound)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/увидеть/", увидеть)
    http.HandleFunc("/добавить/", добавить)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Файл шаблон.html.

```
{.repeated section сообщение} <p>{@}</p> {.end}
<form action="/добавить/" method="POST">
    <div>
        <textarea name="body" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Сохранить">
    </div>
</form>
```

Запустить как

```
8g гостевая.go && 8l гостевая.8 && ./8.out
```

и смотреть на

```
localhost:8080/увидеть/
```

Answer (score 2):

Только для server-side

p.s. хэшкод написан на go. Некоторые штучки в google тоже